# How to add new record without losing existing record in datagridview c# winforms app

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview

i am developing a simple winform application in c#.net with sql server database. My application is about question bank. I want to create exam paper from this question bank. Everything is working fine but the problem is that when i add random questions from selected subject and chapter it loads perfectly in the datagridview but when i want to add question from chapter 2 or 3 etc the previous record cleared and new data added to the grid. I want to add new record without losing previous record which is loaded in datagridview. Anyone can help me in this issue?

```
 DataTable t = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"select top {QuestionsNumericUpDown.Value} *from DescriptiveQuestions where Difficulty_Level='{DiffComboBox.Text}' and Chapter='{ChapterComboBox.Text}' and Course='{CourseComboBox.Text}' order by newid()", c);
                c.Open();
                t.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                c.Close();
                DescriptiveGrid.DataSource = t;
```

Comment: In my small tests… the issue you are having is because the code is “creating” a new `DataTable` each time the code is called… don’t do that… Set `DataTable t = new DataTable();` as a “global variable.” Then each time you call the above code… MINUS the `DataTable t = new DataTable();` line of code… then this should “add” the query result to the existing table `t`.  Also, it will be unnecessary to execute the line… `DescriptiveGrid.DataSource = t;` … if you set this globally outside this code. You should only have to set it once.

Comment: I 'll try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, because you mix the source of your data with the displayed data.

### MVVM: separate your data handling from the way it is displayed

In modern programming, there is a tendency to separate your data and its operations (= model), from how it is displayed (= view). This has the advantage that you can reuse the model for a completely different view. You can for instance display the data in a Graph. Similarly you can reuse the view for other similar data.

It is also easier to unit test the data handling without any display classes: you don't need a form to test the data. And finally: while there is no real data yet, you can use mock data to test the views.

We need a special adapter class to attach the Model to the View: the ViewModel class. Together these three classes are abbreviated as MVVM. Consider to read some background information about this.

### Back to your Question

So let's suppose you have removed the data from your form, and put it in a separate class. This class knows how and where to fetch your data, how to update it, where to store it, how to add new elements etc.

Your application needs to display Questions. Maybe also some Answers? Not handled here, but after you've separated the Model from the View, you can add Answers, without interfering with your current View.

Methods might be like this:

```
interface IQuestionBank
{
    IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions(...);
    void AddQuestion(Question question);
}
```

The exact interface is not important here, you seem to have the concept of chapters and subjetc, and maybe random questions. Adjust your interface such that your form can get the information that must be displayed.

In your form you decide that you want to display the fetched data in a DataGridView. Using visual studio designer you have added a DataGridView and the columns. In the constructor you decide which column should display which Question property:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // which column shows which property
    this.columnQuestionId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Question.Id);
    this.columnQuestionText.DataPropertyName = nameof(Question.Text);
    this.columnQuestionDate.DataPropertyname = nameof(Question.Date);
    ...
}

// the Model is outside the form:
private IQuestionBank QuestionBank {get; } = ...
```

Somewhere the Form has a procedure to fetch the questions that must be displayed from the QuestionBank, depending on several other properties of the form (Chapter, Subject? examinator? student name?)

```
private IEnumerable<Question> FetchQuestionsToDisplay(...)
{
    this.QuestionBank. ... // TODO implement out of scope of this question
}
```

To display the questions, als you have to do is fetch them, and add them to the DataSource of the DataGridView

```
this.DataGridView1.DataSource = this.FetchQuestionsToDisplay(...).ToList();
```

Although this will display the questions, changes made by the operator are not recorded. If you want to be allow the operator to change the displayed information, edit some cells, maybe add new Questions or remove Questions, you need to put the questions in a BindingList:

```
private BindingList<Question> DisplayedQuestions
{
    get => (BindingList<Question>)this.DataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.DataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}
```

After the operator has edited Questions, added some Questions and removed several Questions, he indicates that he has finished editing by pressing the OK button:

```
private void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // fetch the displayed questions:
    ICollection<Question> displayedQuestions = this.DisplayedQuestions;

    // Find out which Questions are changed and process them:
    this.ProcessQuestions(displayedQuestions);
}
```

After a while, some Questions are displayed, and you want to display more questions. Your problem is that the original Questions are removed. Because we separated the Model from the View, it is easy to add some more Questions to the View.

```
private IEnumerable<Question> FetchAdditionalQuestions(...)
{
    // fetch the additional questions that must be displayed.
    // out of scope of this question
    ...
}

private void ShowAdditionalQuestions()
{
    IEnumerable<Question> originalQuestions = this.DisplayedQuestions;
    IEnumerable<Question> additionalQuestions = this.FetchAdditionalQuestions();
    IEnumerable<Question> allQuestions = originalQuestions.Concate(additionalQuestions);

    this.DisplayedQuestions = new BindingList<Question>(allQuestions.ToList());
}
```

I create a new BindingList. Alternatively you could add the additionalQuestions one by one to the BindingList that has the original questions. Not sure which method is better.

### Some other useful methods

Because you separated your model from the view, it is easy to get the selected questions:

```
private Question CurrentQuestion => (Question)this.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

private IEnumerable<Question> SelectedQuestions =>
    this.DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
        .Cast<Question>();
```